# throw an error message when user selects items more than 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following view that i need to display an error message when user tries to submit with items selected greater than 5. I could do this on the controller side but could i use jquery in the view to do this? I think jquery would be lot easier and faster.

Here is my code:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <h1>Manage Testimonials</h1>
    <p><b>Please select up to 5 testimonials you want to include for your sales flyers. A maximum of only 5 testimonials is allowed.</b></p>
<div>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" rules="all">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="padding: 2px 0 2px 2px;">Select</td>
            <td align="center" style="padding: 2px 0 2px 2px;">First Name</td>
            <td align="center" style="padding: 2px 0 2px 2px;">Last Name</td>
            <td align="center" style="padding: 2px 0 2px 2px;">Testimonial</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @{ var i = 0;
}
    @foreach (var testimonials in Model.Testimonials)
    {
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 2px 0 2px 2px;">
            @Html.CheckBox("Testimonials[" + i.ToString() + "].DisplayTestimonials", testimonials.DisplayTestimonials.Value, new { @class = "chkItems" })
            @Html.Hidden("Testimonials[" + i.ToString() + "].ResponseId", testimonials.ResponseId.ToString())
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 2px 0 2px 2px;">@Html.Label(testimonials.FirstName)</td>
        <td style="padding: 2px 0 2px 2px;">@Html.Label(testimonials.LastName)</td>
        <td style="padding: 2px 0 2px 2px;">@Html.Label("Testimonials[" + i.ToString() + "].Question5Answer", testimonials.Question5Answer.ToString())</td>
    </tr>
       i++;
    }
</table>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" id="Submit" value="Save" class="PremierSubmitButton" /></p>
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't rely on javascript, always validate data on server side. Maybe user disabled javascript in browser. use Ajax form reqest if you need ajax for this.

Stay DRY ;)

Comment: I just did my check on the server side. Thanks for the advice.